# When certain link is clicked, how to remove outer element and everything inside the outer element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I remove a link's containing div(and all the other elements inside) when the link is clicked?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">Content</div>
    <a class="remove-outer" href="">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">Content</div>
    <a class="remove-outer" href="">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">Content</div>
    <a class="remove-outer" href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

There are three div containers with the same class. How would I make it so when the user clicks on the link, it removes everything from the container inwards? So, if one of the links above is clicked, it would yield this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">Content</div>
    <a class="remove-outer" href="">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">Content</div>
    <a class="remove-outer" href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

I am pretty new. I only know how to remove elements with a unique id. I cannot apply that knowledge here since if the user clicks on one of the links, all of the containers will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$(function(){
    $("a.remove-outer").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

EDIT: Use live if functionality is needed for newly added elements too.

```
$(function(){
    $("a.remove-outer").live("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, this works if the parent element exists when the page is already loaded, but it doesn't work when I add a new element using JQuery, and then try to remove it using this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
$('a.remove-outer').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('.container').remove(); // find the nearest ancestor element with the class container and remove it
});
```

Comment: why $(this).closest('.container') ?  why not just $(this).parent().remove() ?

Comment: @Brian I generally prefer to use `closest` because it is less likely to break if the DOM changes for whatever reason.